# Inheritance and Polymorphism with service and providers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn Angular2 but have a bit of trouble. I have an abstract Service class called `ParentService`

```
export abstract class ParentService {

}
```

and another Service class that extends `ParentService` called `ChildService`

```
export class ChildService extends ParentService {

}
```

Then I have a component class called `input.component`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { ParentService } from "./service/parent.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html'
})
export class InputComponent {
    constructor(private parentService: ParentService) {}

}
```

And in my `app.component` I provide an instance of the ChildService

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildService } from './service/child.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ChildService]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

However, this doesn't work. It builds fine, but when running the app I get an 
error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:4:16 caused by: No provider for ParentService!
```

Is this possible to do? I just want the `input.component` to know a `ParentService`. I don't really want it to know the implementation.

Comment: You should avoid this pattern

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you elaborate why it would be bad?

Comment: Inheritance should be kept to a minimum in any language and especially in JavaScript. Since JavaScript lacks interfaces and TypeScript interfaces are structural I see a lot of people trying to use classes as interfaces. This is a terrible practice. You should program to interfaces, not to implementations. This is true even in languages lacking manifest interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect Angular2 to automatically wire up sub-classes to original class declaration like that. What if you have 2 sub-classes `DogService` and `CatService` that both inherit `AnimalService` declared in `providers` list, which one should be used?

Instead, you will need to specify it explicitly:

```
providers: [{provide: ParentService, useClass: ChildService}]
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but with a little addition.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [{provide: ParentService, useClass: ChildService}]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

The gotcha here is that DI in angular 2 will not try to infer any relations between classes. So, by default in order to inject ParentService you **must** provide ParentService, period. But luckily we can override this behavior with the construct above. It tells DI container literally "if someone asks for ParentService then create and give them an instance of ChildService instead".

Comment: This was giving me the error "No provider for ChildService!" now. Do I have to provide an instance of ChildService from my app.module to my app.component? I tried that and it works now. So I'm guessing AppComonent doesn't create the instance of ChildService.

Comment: Sorry ignore that comment. I still had ChildService in a few components. That is why I was getting the error. All good now. Thanks!